Can't broadcast sequence, trying to calculate magnetic field over meshgrid
I am trying to calculate the magnetic field from a magnetic dipole located somewhere in the scene using a meshgrid calculation.  I am running into the problem that python doesn't like how I am doing the calculation.
import numpy as np

u0 = 4*np.pi*10**-7 #permeability of free space
N = 10 #number of coils
I = 1e-3 #current in each coil in amps
r = 0.5 #radius of coil in meters
A = np.pi*r**2 #area of coil
nHat = np.array([0,0,1]) #orientation of coil in 3 space

m = N*I*A*nHat #calculating the magnetic dipole associated with the coils

x = np.arange(-10,10,1) #x and y extent over which to calculate magnetic field intensity
y = np.arange(-10,10,1)

X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y) #generate meshgrid

rM = np.array([0,10]) #location of magnetic dipole
B = u0/(4*np.pi) * (m/(np.linalg.norm(np.array([X,Y]) - rM))**3) #calculate the magnetic field at all points in space

I figured I would be able to calculate the magnetic field through vector notation using a meshgrid approach.  I would like to do this so I can plot this using contourf later.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

python doesn't like how I am doing the calculation - that's a new way saying it does not work :)   Try showing us the actual error(s). Full error!

If the problem is in the last B line, split it up into several to better isolate the problem expression.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Well, your vector m has shape (3,) and the quantity that you are trying to divide by is 2-dimensional with a very different size, and the whole thing is complexified by subtracting the position of the dipole.
The best that I could come up with for this outer product was to (mis)use numpy.einsum:
B = u0/(4*np.pi) * np.einsum('a,bc->abc', m, 1.0 / ( (X-rM[0]) ** 2 + (Y-rM[1]) ** 2 + SMALL ) ** 1.5 )

(Note that I had to include the quantity SMALL to prevent division by 0 at one point.)
Are you sure that your expression for B is correct?
Anyway the whole thing is:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

u0 = 4*np.pi*10**-7 #permeability of free space
N = 10 #number of coils
I = 1e-3 #current in each coil in amps
r = 0.5 #radius of coil in meters
A = np.pi*r**2 #area of coil
nHat = np.array([0,0,1]) #orientation of coil in 3 space

m = N*I*A*nHat #calculating the magnetic dipole associated with the coils

x = np.linspace(-10,10,21) #x and y extent over which to calculate magnetic field intensity
y = np.linspace(-10,10,21)

X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y) # generate meshgrid

rM = np.array([0,10]) # location of magnetic dipole

SMALL = 1.0e-20       # used to stop division by 0
B = u0/(4*np.pi) * np.einsum('a,bc->abc', m, 1.0 / ( (X-rM[0]) ** 2 + (Y-rM[1]) ** 2 + SMALL ) ** 1.5 )

c = plt.contourf( X, Y, np.log10( B[2] ), levels=np.linspace( -14, -5, 10 ), extend='both' )
plt.colorbar( c )
plt.title( 'log10(Bz)' )
plt.show()

Output:

